# How do i block my magento extension to use in a unregistered domain

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions, encryption-key

I am working on magento custom module development and sales. usually i encrypt the extension code and install it on my client's websites so that they cannot re-use the extension in other domains.

Now i am looking for some other method through which i can stop others using my code other than encryption.

I heard about setting up license key to validate user's domain.Can anyone provide me more details or ideas about this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The best thing that you can do is to is to rely on your license and have a team of lawyers on speed-dial.  PHP source code encryption (IE ioncube) is easily reversible by anyone outside of the script-kiddie world and should not be relied upon.  Once the encryption is stripped away and all of your licensing code has been neatly removed, all that you have backing you up is your legal team.

Answer (score 5):

You could also put in a few callbacks to your domain to validate a key but again as with the encryption it is not really in the spirit of things.

For the callbacks you can hook onto one of the main events like `core_block_abstract_to_html_before`

Answer (score 3):

There really isn't any way to do this, except encrypting your entire module. But then less people will use it, because who knows what code you've put in there.